# Variable passed to new screen is blank - react navigation issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I'm trying to pass a simple variable to a new screen and I followed this guide exactly:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/. I confirmed that the variable I'm passing exists and is the correct value, but in the new screen, when I try to print or use it, it is completely blank. It doesn't seem to exist. What am I missing?

**Original (sending) screen (jump to the button near the bottom that sends navigation.navigate and passes the number of players):**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import {useState} from "react";
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

export default function SetupScreen( {navigation} ){


const [playersOpen, setPlayersOpen] = useState(false);
const [playersValue, setPlayersValue] = useState(null);
const [playersItems, setPlayersItems] = useState([
    {label: '2-Max', value: '2'},
    {label: '6-Max', value: '6'},
    {label: '9-Max', value: '9'}

]);
const onPlayersOpen = useCallback(() => {
    setCityOpen(false);
}, []);

const [blindsOpen, setBlindsOpen] = useState(false);
const [blindsValue, setBlindsValue] = useState(null);
const [blindsItems, setBlindsItems] = useState([
    {label: '$0.01 / $0.02', value: '0.02'},
    {label: '$0.05 / $0.10', value: '0.10'},
    {label: '$0.10 / $0.20', value: '0.20'},
    {label: '$0.25 / $0.50', value: '0.50'},
    {label: '$0.50 / $1.00', value: '1'},
    {label: '$1 / $2', value: '2'},
    {label: '$2 / $5', value: '5'},
    {label: '$5 / $10', value: '10'}
]);

const onBlindsOpen = useCallback(() => {
    setCountryOpen(false);
}, []);


return (

    <View style={styles.container}>

        <View>

            <Text>Select Table Size</Text>

            <DropDownPicker
                zIndex = {3000}
                zIndexInverse = {1000}
                open={playersOpen}
                value={playersValue}
                items={playersItems}
                setOpen={setPlayersOpen}
                setValue={setPlayersValue}
                setItems={setPlayersItems}
            />

            <Text>Select stakes</Text>

            <DropDownPicker
                zIndex = {2000}
                zIndexInverse = {2000}
                open={blindsOpen}
                value={blindsValue}
                items={blindsItems}
                setOpen={setBlindsOpen}
                setValue={setBlindsValue}
                setItems={setBlindsItems}
            />

        </View>

        <View style={styles.buttonSection}>

            <Text>Players: {JSON.stringify(playersValue)}</Text>
            <Text>Blinds: {JSON.stringify(blindsValue)}</Text>

            <Button
                zIndex = {1000}
                title={"Begin Session"}
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate('SessionScreen', {
                      PV: playersValue,
                    });
                }}
            />
            <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />
            <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />

        </View>
    </View>

        
    );

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
       flexDirection: 'column',
       justifyContent: 'space-between',
       alignItems: 'center',
       backgroundColor: 'green',
    },
    buttonSection: {
        height: 300
    },
})
```

**Destination Screen (The command in question is right at the top)**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react'
import {useState} from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';



export default function SessionScreen ( {route, navigation} ) {

const {tableSize, setTableSize} = useState(route.params)

const [players, setPlayers] = useState(tableSize)
const [bigBlind, setBigBlind] = useState(2)
const [progress, setProgress] = useState("Initialization")
const [activePlayer, setActivePlayer] = useState(0)
const [handRecord, setHandRecord] = useState("")



const nextStage = () => {

    setProgress("Preflop")

}


var makeArray = (numP) => {

    var array = [
        <Button title="Hero" key={0} />,
        <Button title="Villain 1" key={1}/>,
        <Button title="Villain 2" key={2}/>,
        <Button title="Villain 3" key={3}/>,
    ]

    if (numP >= 6) {
        array.push([<Button title="Villain 4" key={4}/>,
        <Button title="Villain 5" key={5}/>])
    }

    if (numP === 9) {
        array.push([<Button title="Villain 6" key={6}/>,
        <Button title="Villain 7" key={7}/>,  <Button title="Villain 8" key={8}/>])
    }


    return array

}



return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>

        <View>
        <Text>
            Players: {JSON.stringify(tableSize)}</Text>
            {makeArray(players)}
        </View>

        <View>
            <Text>Session Screen</Text>

            {/* {progress === "Initialization" &&
                <Button title="nextRound" onPress={() => nextStage()}/>
            }

            {progress === "Preflop" &&
                //<Button title="add player" onPress={() => this.setState({players: 6})}/>
                <Text>Got to second if</Text>
            } */}

            <Text>Got past second if</Text>

            <Button
                title="Go to History Screen"
                onPress={() => navigation.push('HistoryScreen')}
            />
            <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />
            <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />

            
            
            
        </View>

        <View>
            <Text>{progress}</Text>

        </View>
    </View>

);



}


const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
       flexDirection: 'column',
       justifyContent: 'space-between',
       alignItems: 'center',
       backgroundColor: 'green',
    },
    buttonSection: {
        height: 300
    },
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need the useState. Can you try this instead:
const {tableSize, setTableSize} = route.params

Comment: Hey, unfortunately that didn't change anything - the variable is still not interacting with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the `tableSize`? Just get the `PV` value from `route.params`:

```
const [players, setPlayers] = useState(route.params.PV)
```